# Scaling mesh along the Normals

Tags: transforms, normals, transform-orientation

anyone knows how to scale an object on its normal's?

as an example (Screen Shot) when I'm scaling this one its does not scale proportionally on each face normal direction, how can I do that ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about the Shrink/Fatten tool and it seems to do the same thing no worries community, I GOT IT :D